# ParcelJS, use Chrome console with a bundled project?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, bundle, parceljs

I've been using Webpack for some time, but it was a little bit too extensive for me.
That's why I wanted to start off with Parcel, to get the basics of bundling projects together.

Let us say I have a basic index.html file, which has a link to a JavaScript file.

Within this javascript file, I have a couple of dependencies imports.

It should look a little bit like this.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Helloo</h1>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and script.js

```
import "../styles/sass/main.scss";
import is from "is_js";

const myString = "Hello World";
```

Now, when I bundle the index.html file using

> parcel bundle index.html --public-url .

i would like to use chrome developer tools console to console (from the console) some javascript as e.g. `myString`

But because parcel bundles everything inside one function, this variable is not accessible and the console returns:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sections is not defined
>       at :1:1

How can i still debug my projects inside the console using parcel as a bundle processor?

Comment: I also am new at Parcel, and was wondered the same thing. One solution I thought of is to assign variables to the window object. Example: `const myString = "Hello world";

window.myString = myString;`

Comment: Is also a possibility, but not a solution for me. I stopped using parcel live server and continued with node-sass and live-server modules for development. Since I don't have any imports inside the js file i dont need Babel, Parcel or browserify for development purposes